# How can I replace C# windows forms executable application icon?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2005, icons

I already finished my development. But I don't like the windows icon for the executable application.

How to replace the default windows icon with my favorite one? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/467947-how-set-icon-winform

First is the Project configuration properties where you have set the Application icon. The
other is in each individual form's properties where you set the Form's icon -
which can be the same icon